# Given a microsecond value , how to accurately get a timeval struct? /*UPDATE GETTING NEGATIVE VALUE*/

Tags: c++, timestamp, double, rounding

Is this the right way to convert a microseconds and represent it as a timeval in my application ? I require the usage of a struct timeval and the above code is part of a routine that converts a double microsecond to a timeval

NEGATIVE Value in this code

//UPDATE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

void convert(uint64_t offset , struct timeval t)
{

std::cout <<  "currentTimeOffset " << offset / 1000000 << "startTimeOffset " << t.tv_sec  << std::endl;
t.tv_usec =  offset % 1000000L;
std::cout <<  "stattime usec " <<  t.tv_usec << std::endl ;


}

int main(int argc , char** argv)
{

struct timeval test;

uint64_t t = 18446744073709551615;
convert(t , test);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question looks more like a math question, on how to convert from microseconds to seconds.

Comment: My question was particularly about rounding errors ? is this conversion accurate

Comment: Why are you dividing by a float and then truncating to an integer?  You could save some steps by dividing by an integer.

Comment: You loose precision when dividing, then truncating to an integer.

Comment: The best accuracy is to keep the units in microseconds, but use a wider variable, such as `unsigned long` or `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
timeval to_timeval(double usec) {
    return { usec / 1000000, usec % 1000000 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. I am not a expert at rounding errors but I think generally the less work you do with floating numbers the more accurate.

On that principle I would be tempted to convert the number to integer just once and then break that down without using floats like this:

```
timeval convert(double microseconds)
{
    long u = std::round(microseconds);

    timeval time;
    time.tv_sec = u / 1000000;
    time.tv_usec = u - (time.tv_sec * 1000000);

    return time;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be more 100,000 that needs to be used than 1,000,000 ?

Comment: @solsTiCe I don't think so. If there are `1,000,000` microseconds in a second then isn't each microsecond just `1 / 1,000,000` seconds? Therefor isn't `u` microseconds `u / 1,000,000` seconds?